# C++0x auto, decltype and template functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been reading [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/cpp10.aspx) CodeProject article on C++0x and have given it a quick try in VC2010. However I've run into a compile error and I'm at a bit of a loss as to what the problem is.

```
#include < iostream>

template <typename FirstType, typename SecondType>
auto  AddThem(FirstType t1, SecondType t1) -> decltype(t1 + t2)
{
    return t1 + t2;
}

int main()
{

    auto a = 3.14;
    auto b = 3;
    auto c = AddThem<decltype(a),decltype(b)>(a,b);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Results in this error:

> > error C2086: 'FirstType t1' : redefinition 1>          main.cpp(4) :
> >     see declaration of 't1'
> >     1>main.cpp(14): error C2780:
> >     ''unknown-type' AddThem(FirstType)' :
> >     expects 1 arguments - 2 provided 1>
> >     main.cpp(4) : see declaration of
> >     'AddThem' 1>main.cpp(14): fatal error
> >     C1903: unable to recover from previous
> >     error(s); stopping compilation

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Just call it as `AddThem(a, b)`, the template parameters will be deduced.

Comment: I think I need more coffee - I'm clearly losing it :( Thanks!

Comment: As a matter of taste, I don't think it is good to lose type definition when you write
    auto a = 3.14;
    auto b = 3;
IMHO I think auto is good to guess long and hardly readable type names, namely within template definition.

Comment: I agree. But I was just playing around with C++0x and wanted to see what using auto was like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It’s because you named both of your parameters `t1`. You probably meant to call the second one `t2`.

Comment: Well no kidding. :( Little embarrassed I missed that!

Comment: @Chris: just blame the compiler for not making it obvious ;)

Comment: What @Matthieu M. said. The compiler error really could be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

That is my mistake. You should have reported on CodeProject itself. I casually found this topic.
Yes, they should be two different names.

Now, one more change I need to do!